# Web site does not allow zooming out or scrolling on iOS

Tags: html, safari, ios6, mobile-safari, viewport

Part of our web site has a mobile version, but for the Blogs section (all our PHP content) we decided to just offer mobile users the desktop site (for now).

This works fine on iPad, but on iPhone (iPhone 4S/iOS6 tested) the page loads zoomed into the top left corner and you can't zoom out or even scroll sideways to the content that's cut off.

I have tried playing with the meta viewport tags, but no combination of parameters seems to fix this. I have tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, initial-scale=.75, user-scalable=yes" />`

Please view this URL on an iPhone : http://www.finecooking.com/blogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching on your css if you set an specific height or an `overflow: hidden` to the body or html or maybe a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you Craig for the [answer](//stackoverflow.com/questions/13593271/web-site-does-not-allow-zooming-out-or-scrolling-on-ios/23980880#answer-17204675), as it turns out you can have `overflow:hidden` on `body`, but not on `html`.

In my case this broke also the scroll in an embedded `iframe`, which is weird, but the css down below fixed it.

### Scroll won't work:

```
html, body {
    /*common stuff */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Scroll will work:

```
html, body {
    /* common stuff */
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me in iPad, and iPhone:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Comment: Not for what I'm trying to do.When I tried your code the site was zoomed in all the way, I still could not zoom back out or scroll horizontally to see the cropped content.

Comment: That syntax is wrong, it should be: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />